# How to use launch4j for warpping Java 9 apps

Tags: java, wrapper

I'm using launch4j (current version) and I can't figure out the using for Java 9. My config file contains this element:

```
<jre>
  <minVersion>1.9.0</minVersion>
  <maxVersion></maxVersion>
</jre>
```

But after wrapping and starting the exe file I get the error message that no JRE 1.9.0 is installed.

Comment: They have changed the reported Java version scheme. On my machine, `java -version` outputs `java version "9.0.4"`

Comment: Ok, I changed my config to <minVersion>9.0.4</minVersion> but it has no effect. Java 9.0.4 is installed on my system and the wrapper now prompts for 9.0.4. Curious.

Comment: I don't know if launch4j is actively maintained but there is at least one issue in their issue tracker asking about JDK 9 support: https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/177/